# Can Windows XP Mode access the telephone port on a computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode, phone, telephony

I would like to use my Windows 7 PC as a telephone. I know of an undocumented feature called Phone Dialer (`C:\Windows\System32\dialer.exe`), but the interface of it is quite minimalistic and does not contain as many features as the same utility in Windows XP (including the ability to receive calls). Since my computer is running Windows 7 Professional and therefore contains Windows XP Mode, is it possible that it can access my computer's telephone port so that I can use the Phone Dialer in Windows XP to place and receive telephone calls?

When I go into Device Manager on Windows XP Mode, it does not recognize any modem connected to the computer. However, Windows 7 does and I can place phone calls properly on Windows 7, but it doesn't work in Windows XP Mode. My laptop is a Sony VGN-Z56TG with a custom install of Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

Comment: "Is it possible?" - Depends on what type of "Phone port" you're talking about, and you haven't shared that information with us.  Is it an analog modem?  USB or PCI?  Does the device appear in the XP Mode's device manager?  What happened when you tried to use it (in XP Mode)?

Comment: It is my laptop's built-in phone port. Haven't I made it obvious?

Comment: Has anyone tried this yet?

Comment: @gparyani - What is the built-in phone port connected to?  I would assume its some sort of modem which then requires knowing what interface its connected to.  Virtual PC that handles the Windows XP Mode does not have the capability to virtualize certain type of hardware.  In other words more information is required.

Comment: @gparyani - **You were expected to do this before you asked the question**

Comment: This isn't a "Please do it for me website". This is a "I've tried it and now I'm very stuck, anyone have experience with this?" website

Comment: @gparyani if it is your laptop, please include it in the topic when you edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*gparyani*: You're asking about the modem, right? Well, you'd need an app which would digitize the speech coming in on the modem, pass it to the audio card, and then turn it back into analog audio so you could use it with a headset.

Or, you could use the modem just to dial out, and then seize the line with a telephone and use the phone to talk on it. Some phone dialer apps are shown at http://www.phonedialerpro.com/ and then you'd need a phone line splitter (readily available at any Radio Shack) and a phone (probably one with a headset, or maybe a speakerphone?)